# Problems with extracting information from the Sessonstarage

Tags: javascript, web, local-storage, session-storage

I have problems with extracting the data from the sessionstorage and then putting the data in a vector to be able to traverse their positions, To see if the textarea were declared two variables with the same name, is for a project of a compiler

```
 var data = [];

function extraersesson() {


var medidor = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.length);

for (var i = 0; i < medidor; i++) {

    //var cap = information of sessionstorage
    var cap = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(i));


    data.push(cap);

    console.log(data[i] + " dataaa");

    if (data[i] == data[i + 1]) {

        console.log("the data is the same");

    }

   }

 }
```

But my problem arises here:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hgSz.png)

Data is well saved in the sessionstorage

But when I want to extract and compare it gives me the problem

In the console. Log you can see that it carries the data but does not enter the If

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRgZU.png)

And do not run the other console. Log and just like I did as follows:

```
 function extraersesson() {


var medidor = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.length);

for (var i = 0; i < medidor; i++) {



    if (JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(i)) == JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(i+1))) {

        console.log("the data is the same");

    }


  }

 }
```

In summary I want to compare two values that are stored in the Sessionstorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can following code to get that output

```
function extraersesson() {
  var data = [], medidor = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < medidor; i++) {
    var cap = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(i));
    if (data.indexOf(cap) >= 0) {
      console.log("The data is same");
    } else {
      data.push(cap);
    }
  }
}
```